# How to share Opera extensions preferences between my two computers?

Tags: sync, opera, widgets

Well, the title is quite unambiguous.
However, let me clarify it even more.

Starting with [Opera 11](http://www.opera.com/browser/), there now are [Opera extensions](https://addons.opera.com/addons/extensions/), which are compliant to [W3C widget specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/widgets/). This allows us to use it on whichever browser supports their (well, currently, only Opera does). Anyway, suppose I have two computers, each one using Opera. How could I possibly synchronize used extensions and their preferences ?

- With [Opera Link](https://link.opera.com/) ? I didn't saw any kind of extension sharing in it
- With Dropbox/any other file sharing application ? If so, how could I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sync your Opera widgets folder with [Dropbox](http://wiki.dropbox.com/TipsAndTricks/SyncOtherFolders) by linking the widgets folder into your Dropbox. For example, in Linux you can link the folders like so:

`ln -s /home/user/.opera/widgets /home/user/Dropbox/widgets`